# Extract GPS track from TomTom Bandit videos

Tags: gps, video, exif, exifread

I would like to extract GPS tracks with a commandline-tool from videos recorded with a TomTom Bandit action cam .
There is the proprietary software of TomTom to extract the tracks but I need something that I can use from the commandline to use it inside a script.

I asked a question on TomTom discussions but seem no one has an idea yet:

https://discussions.tomtom.com/en/discussion/1040314/extract-gps-tracks-from-tomtom-bandit-videos-by-command-line#latest

Comment: what file format is bandit using? (reading up right click and export to kml seems to work)

Comment: @Mapperz it's mp4

Comment: see mp4parser > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157114/how-to-extract-gps-information-from-garmin-cam-20-video-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my question in the exiftool forum and the exiftool author Phil Harvey implemented the functionality to extract the gps tracks with exiftool:

http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,9930.0.html

```
exiftool -p ~/path_to_my_gpx_fmt/gpx.fmt -ee -ext mp4 -w %f.gpx
```